# Access Array of objects inside another object in React State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

**By first, I used to have this state:**

```
const [object, setObject] = useState({
    var1: 'value 1',
    var2: 'value 2',
    var3: 'value 3',
    booleanVar: false
});
```

When I wanted to update the values I was doing this:

```
const newState = {
    var1: 'new value 1',
    var2: 'new value 2'
}

setObject(prevState => ({ ...prevState, ...newState }));
```

---

**The example above works pretty well, but now I have this another state that contains an object, inside this object I have an array of objects.**

```
const [object, setObject] = useState({
    array: [
        {
            var1: 'value 1',
            var2: 'value 2',
            var3: 'value 3'
        }
    ],
    booleanVar: false
});
```

What is the proper way to access and update the objects inside the array?

And how could I add another object inside the array?

Is there a simple way to do it just like I was doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const stateCopy = {...state};

stateCopy.array[0].var1 = 'foo';

setObject(stateCopy);
```